# Image Cropping issue using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am currently facing an issue regarding image sorting using boostrap blade.php file. I am looking to sort the images neatly in my website but it seems that some images have partially cropped out, and it does not loos good. I want the images to be neatly sorted in desktop view and mobile view of the website. There is also an issue regarding two images overlapping each other in mobile view.
The images i hope are neatly sorted with a considerate amount of spacing and gap between them.

[Desktop view where you can see some images like the one that has a bee has some part of it cut out of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFWWR.png)

[Mobile view where you can see there seems to be two images overlapping each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8xnP.png)

The code I am using is below:

```
<ul class="client_icon">
<li class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <img src="{{ asset('images/new_client_icon/J&T.png') }}" alt="j&t" class="img-fluid"
        style="max-width: 45vw; height: auto; min-width: 100px;" />
</li>
<li class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <img src="{{ asset('images/new_client_icon/Albee.png') }}" alt="petronas" class="img-fluid"
        style="max-width: 45vw; height: auto; min-width: 100px;" />
</li>
<li class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <img src="{{ asset('images/new_client_icon/beaconhospital.jpg') }}" alt="beacon" class="img-fluid"
        style="max-width: 45vw; height: auto; min-width: 100px;" />
</li>
```

I have use various method of bootstrap to try to fix the issue. Sometimes even have the problem of them become square sized where if the images does not fit within will be crop or squeezed until it fits in the square box. Also have use some ways other than the listed li class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 method but this is the closest i can get to my desired result

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to fix the issue a bit. It looks a bit better. My solution for this is change the max-width, height and also the min width.

Currently i change it using object-fit: contain and alter the max width and height values.

```
<li class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-3"><a href="https://www.jtexpress.my/index.php" target="_blank"><img
      src="{{ asset('images/new_client_icon/J&T.png') }}" alt="j&t" class="img-fluid"
      style="max-width: 100%; height: 120px; object-fit: contain; " /></a></li>
<li class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-3"><a href="http://www.albeeexpress.my/" target="_blank"><img
      src="{{ asset('images/new_client_icon/Albee.png') }}" alt="petronas" class="img-fluid"
      style="max-width: 100%; height: 120px; object-fit: contain; " /></a></li>
<li class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-3"><a href="https://www.beaconhospital.com.my/" target="_blank"><img
      src="{{ asset('images/new_client_icon/beaconhospital.jpg') }}" alt="beacon" class="img-fluid"
      style="max-width: 100%; height: 120px; object-fit: contain; " /></a></li>
```

[Picture of site after changes: Desktop View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwZr5.png)

[Picture of site after changes: Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQUOF.png)